# Getting 400 error code without any more details for tokenInfo API in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to fetch google auth scopes granted by user using this code.

```
    final oauth2Api = Oauth2Api(client);

    final tokenInfo = await oauth2Api.tokeninfo();

    final grantedScopes = tokenInfo.scope;
```

I verified that the client is not null and I'm fetching it using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth).

Sometimes, the tokenInfo api throws this error:

`DetailedApiRequestError (DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: No error details. HTTP status was: 400.))`

This error is very unpredictible and occurs less than 10% of the time but it's breaking a major flow in our app. Please guide me what I'm doing wrong or how to debug it.

Comment: I don't think that method does what you think it does.   please link to the docs where it states it is possible to see what scopes a user has authorized

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo, Check `getScope` method here https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/oauth2/model/Tokeninfo.html . I cannot find dart specific docs, but whenever it returns a valid response(which it returns in most cases), there is a scope field, containing all scopes granted by the user.

Comment: That just returns the scopes for a specific Token not all the scopes granted by a user

Comment: Yes. I need scope for that particular token instance only. Is there any other way to get this data?